# If $M$ is connected then there exists exactly two orientations on $M$.

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be orientable

a) Prove that if $M$ is connected then there exists exactly two orientations on $M$.

b) What happens if $M$ is not connected?

### My attempt

a) Consider isomorphisms $\phi,\psi:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow V$ for a vector space $V$ of dimension $m$. $M$ is either orientation preserving or orientation reversing. So, by definitions,  $det(\phi^{-1} \circ \psi)>0$ or $det(\phi^{-1} \circ \psi)<0$, (determinents are positive or negative).

b) Consider two disjoint circles in a plane... There is a total of $4$ orienations here since each circle has 2 orientations.
... not sure where to go with this...

Comment: Statement (a) is false. There might be zero orientations.

Comment: edit: @JackLee , we are assuming that $M$ is orientable

Comment: You did it right. For part b), just say that for each connected component of $M$, we can choose an orientation independently of the orientations of the components. So if we have $k$ connected components of $M$, then the number of orientations is $2^k$.

Comment: I don't understand your argument for (a) at all. What do $\phi$ and $\psi$ have to do with $M$? What does it mean to say "$M$ is either orientation preserving or orientation reversing"?  A smooth map or a linear map can be orientation-preserving or reversing, but not a manifold.

Comment: @JackLee http://www.math.uconn.edu/~parzygnat/math3151s17/3151Spring2017Notes.pdf page 142 has the definition I used for my argument.

Comment: I think you're confusing "orientation of a vector space" (Definition 15.2 in the link you cited) with "orientation of a manifold" (Definition 15.3). The exercise you quoted is referring to the latter definition, which is considerably more complicated.

Comment: @JackLee you are right, i was confusing those definitions!

Comment: @JackLee how should I got about this?